# Observer pattern with objects as observers

Tags: javascript

I've implemented the **observer pattern** using **functions** as observers, and it seems to work as intended:

```js
const subjectElem       = document.getElementById('subject');
const observerOneElem   = document.getElementById('observer-1');
const observerTwoElem   = document.getElementById('observer-2');
const subscribeOneElem  = document.getElementById('subscribe-1');
const subscribeTwoElem  = document.getElementById('subscribe-2');

const subject   = new Subject();

// Using functions as Observers
const observer1 = function (data) {
  observerOneElem.value = data;
};

const observer2 = function (data) {
  observerTwoElem.value = data;
};

subscribeOneElem.addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    subject.add(observer1);
  } else {
    subject.remove(observer1);
  }
});

subscribeTwoElem.addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    subject.add(observer2);
  } else {
    subject.remove(observer2)
  }
});

subjectElem.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  // notify all subscribed observers
  subject.setState(event.target.value);
});

function Subject() {
  this.observers = [];            // observers list
  this._state = '';
}

Subject.prototype.add = function (observer) {
  this.observers.push(observer);
}

Subject.prototype.remove = function (observer) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < this.observers.length) {
    if (this.observers[i] === observer)
      break;
    i++;
  }
  this.observers.splice(i, 1);
}

Subject.prototype.setState = function (data) {
  this._state = data;
  this.observers.forEach(observer => {
    observer(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Sandbox</title>
  <style>
    .row {
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      padding: 1%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
  <h1>Observer Pattern</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <label for="subject">Subject:
        <input type="text" id="subject">
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <label for="observer-1">Observer 1:
        <input type="text" id="observer-1">
      </label>
      <label for="subscribe-1">Subscribe:
        <input type="checkbox" id="subscribe-1" unchecked>
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <label for="observer-2">Observer 2:
        <input type="text" id="observer-2">
      </label>
      <label for="subscribe-2">Subscribe:
        <input type="checkbox" id="subscribe-2" unchecked>
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to know is how to use **objects** as observers, I mean how to wire them up with the **HTML input elements**. I had in mind a constructor like this one:

```js
function Observer() {
  this.notify = function (subject) {
    let currentState = subject.getState();
    this.value = currentState;
    console.log(currentState);        // logs current state (testing)
  }
}
```

Along with a method in the **Subject** like this:

```js
Subject.prototype.getState = function () {
  return this._state;
}
```

But I fail to see how to connect the **input** elements (`observerOneElem` and `observerTwoElem`) with the instances of `Observer`.

Comment: Is there a reason you reinvent the wheel? Otherwise you should use [RXJS](https://rxjs.dev/) for the observer pattern. It's an implementation of the observer pattern with many utility functions and support for browser API and Node.js. Many frameworks like Angular and React use it.

Comment: Yes, curiosity and learning.

Comment: You should learn from years of experience and best practice. Instead of writing your own library you should first see what large groups of developers in large companies have developed. You wouldn't try to reinvent basic mathematics, would you? In RXJS you can see functions and objects as observers.

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent basic mathematics.
I'm not writing my own library.
At the moment I'm not interested in RXJS.

Comment: You asked a question and I told you where you can find the answer. You asked how to create an observer object and I gave you a resource with documentation, tutorials and code examples. You don't have to use the library but you can use it as a template for your own implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't that hard, just had to select the element inside the `Observer` constructor, by passing the **id** when instantiating an **observer**. Now it works with observers implemented as objects. (no puppies were harmed, no libraries were consulted)

```js
const subjectElem       = document.getElementById('subject');
const subscribeOneElem  = document.getElementById('subscribe-1');
const subscribeTwoElem  = document.getElementById('subscribe-2');

const subject = new Subject();

// Using objects as Observers
const observer1 = new Observer('observer-1');
const observer2 = new Observer('observer-2');

subscribeOneElem.addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    subject.add(observer1);
  } else {
    subject.remove(observer1);
  }
});

subscribeTwoElem.addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    subject.add(observer2);
  } else {
    subject.remove(observer2)
  }
});

subjectElem.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  // notify all subscribed observers
  subject.setState(event.target.value);
});

function Subject() {
  this.observers = [];            // observers list
  this._state = '';
}

Subject.prototype.add = function (observer) {
  this.observers.push(observer);
}

Subject.prototype.remove = function (observer) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < this.observers.length) {
    if (this.observers[i] === observer)
      break;
    i++;
  }
  this.observers.splice(i, 1);
}

Subject.prototype.setState = function (data) {
  this._state = data;
  this.observers.forEach(observer => {
    observer.notify(this);
  });
}

Subject.prototype.getState = function () {
  return this._state;
}

function Observer(id) {
  this.observer = document.getElementById(id);
  this.notify = function (subject) {
    let currentState = subject.getState();
    this.observer.value = currentState;
  }
}
```